# Access type parameters of generic parameter scala

Tags: scala, generics, akka-stream, scala-generics

I am trying to make a wrapper on the following function in Akka streams.

```
RestartFlow.withBackoff(minBackoff = 3.seconds,
      maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
      randomFactor = 0.2) {
      () => s
    }
```

where s is some source that I am wrapping with the back off. Ideally id like something like this

```
RetryFlow(s)
```

Ive managed to create this:

```
object RetryFlow {
  def apply[In, Out, _, T <: Flow[In, Out, _]](source: T, minBackoff: FiniteDuration = 3.seconds, maxBackoff: FiniteDuration = 30.seconds, randomFactor: Double = 0.2): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
    RestartFlow.withBackoff(
      minBackoff = minBackoff,
      maxBackoff = maxBackoff,
      randomFactor = randomFactor) {
      () => source
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is I need to supply all 3 type params of the flow again at the call site and it looks horrendous

```
RetryFlow[JustDataEvent, JustDataEvent, NotUsed, Flow[JustDataEvent, JustDataEvent, NotUsed]](s)
```

It's also not type-safe as I could type any type params here.

What I feel like should be possible but I'm not sure how is to not take the extra type params In and Out but do something like T#In, T#Out etc as I've said that T extends flow, therefore, T Already has the type parameters I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about instead of `T`, just taking a parameter of type `Flow[In, Out, _]`?

```
object RetryFlow {
  def apply[In, Out, _](
      source: Flow[In, Out, _],
      minBackoff: FiniteDuration = 3.seconds,
      maxBackoff: FiniteDuration = 30.seconds,
      randomFactor: Double = 0.2): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
    RestartFlow.withBackoff[In, Out](minBackoff = minBackoff,
                            maxBackoff = maxBackoff,
                            randomFactor = randomFactor) { () =>
      source
    }
  }
}
```

And then we get:

```
val value: Flow[Int, String, NotUsed] = Flow.fromFunction[Int, String](i => i.toString)
RetryFlow(value)
```

Comment: Yup works great thank you, I guess i was looking at it from the wrong approach by taking flow as the generic param